# PHP RewriteRule combined with caching

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My problem is that my .htaccess file on a location like: test.example.com/ doesn't redirect. My suspicion is that it is because of the cache rule in the same file. I think that they might interfere, however, I am not experienced with .htaccess files so I might be completely wrong there. Can anyone help me redirect:

```
test.example.com/s/home

to:

test.example.com/?s=home
```

The user is supposed to input: test.example.com/s/home and then test.example.com/index.php should be able to $_GET["s"] without the url in the urlbar changing to the actual url of test.example.com/?s=home

I tried a lot of examples shown on stackoverflow but they didn't work for me.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/s/$ /?s=$1
```

**THIS DOESN'T WORK!!! ^**

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: So what you want is _not_ a redirection, bunt an internal rewrite.

Comment: That example you showed certainly does not work for the task you specify. I actually doubt that you took this from SO, at least from an upvoted answer here... But there are _thousands_ of working solutions here. None of all those worked? _Why not?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the *specific* task you ask about, considering your additional mentioning of an `index.php` routing script I suggest this starting point:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?s/(\w+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1 [END,QSA]
```

You may have to tweak it for your specific situation, though.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).